# Is the syntax for join on stricter than using comma where?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

The following query fails to be parsed:

```
select t.ename, t.received, d.loc from  
(  
  select e.ename, eb.received , e.deptno  
  from emp e left outer join  emp_bonus eb  
  on  
  e.empno=eb.empno  
)  
as t  
join dept as d on d.deptno = t.deptno;
```

with the error:

> Column 'deptno' in field list is ambiguous

**But** this query is parsed succesfully:

```
select t.ename, t.received, d.loc from  
(  
  select e.ename, eb.received , e.deptno  
  from emp e left outer join  emp_bonus eb  
  on  
  e.empno=eb.empno  
)  
as t, dept as d where d.deptno = t.deptno
```

I only changed the `JOIN ON` to `t, dept where`
Why does the first version fail?

Answer (score 1):

the first query runs perfectly in mysql version 5.1
[see the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/4b0d4/1)

Comment: Hm.I am running `5.0.20` from a query browser

Comment: `5.0.20` really? Update to the latest, 5.5 or 5.6 and even if you can't do that - for whatever reasons - update to the latest minor version of 5.0: `5.0.96` This is probably a bug.